# Enable datatable themes in themeroller

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables, themeroller

[According to DataTables.net](http://www.datatables.net/styling/themes) all I need to do to enable themes is enable the option in ThemeRoller:

> DataTables has full support for ThemeRoller created themes, all you
>   need to do is enable the flag in the initialisation object, and the
>   required mark-up and classes will be added by DataTables.

I went to [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) > Gallery > picked the "Start" theme clicked Download.  The first section "UI Core" is the only one that contains the partial word "initializ" and they are all checked by default.  However, my DataTable does not show a theme.

```
    dtRequest = $('#xyzRequests').dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 100,
        "aLengthMenu": [[20, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, -1], [20, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, "All"]]
    });
```

`<table id="xyzRequests">`//...

For testing, I slapped an accordion control in there and that one themes up just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use Theme Roller, you need to enable JQueryUI for data tables

```
$("#myTable_id").dataTable({
             bJQueryUI: true,
             sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
});
```

and make sure you have everything linked correctly on the page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Yoursite.com</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

See http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/5851/using-themeroller-/p1

Comment: The one piece that I was missing is the property:  `bJQueryUI: true,`.  I'm guessing that's what the documentation intended by the vague statement "enable the flag in the initialization object".

Comment: Yes, the documentation wasn't very clear.  I've done it before and I still had to hunt for the correct option name.